# Get the current date as the default argument for a method

Tags: python, datetime

I've got a method:

```
def do_something(year=?, month=?):
    pass
```

I want the `year` and `month` arguments to be optional but I want their default to equal the current year and month. I've thought about setting two variables just before the method declaration but the process this is part of can run for months. It needs to be dynamic.

Seems like it shouldn't be hard but I'm having a mental block today so **how would you do it?**

Answer (score 11):

The idiomatic approach here would be to assign `None` as the default value, and then reassign within the method if the values are still `None`:

```
def do_something(year=None, month=None):
    if year is None:
        year = datetime.date.today().year
    if month is None:
        month = datetime.date.today().month

    # do stuff...
```

You might think that you can do `def do_something(year=datetime.date.today().year)`, but that would cache the value so that `year` would be the same across all calls to `do_something`.

To demonstrate that concept:

```
>>> def foo(x=time.time()): print x
...
>>> foo()
1280853111.26
>>> # wait a second at the prompt
>>> foo()
1280853111.26
```

Comment: `if not year` and `if not month` is more pythonic than `is none`. Otherwise good.

Comment: @Zonda: Perhaps, but that would also invalidate values of zero.  Zero might be a strange value for the month, but it's plausible for the year, without any more context on the OP's exact circumstance.